# What is the grammar for the following context-free language $L=\{w||a|>|b|\}$?

Tags: context-free-grammar

I want to find the grammar for the following context-free language:

$$L=\{w|\mbox{ the number of $a>$ the number of $b$ }\}$$

I tried the following :

\begin{align*}
S&\rightarrow a|aK\\
K&\rightarrow\varepsilon |(ab)^*|a^*|bS
\end{align*}

But it doesn't reach words with series of $b$ such as $aaaabbba$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,
$$S \to AS'bS' | bS'AS' | A $$
$$S' \to AS'bS' | bS'AS' | A | \varepsilon$$
$$A \to a | aA$$

I constructed this by taking a CFG for $L = \{ w : |a| = |b| \}$, and adding an intermediate state for $a$'s.

Comment: You can't have $S \to \varepsilon$ as an initial step, as it would allow to have an empty set and I don't know if $|a|>|b|$ then

Comment: True, I've corrected my answer.